# Implementing toggle menu for mobile, but whole nav bar is clickable and I want just the button to be clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay, I'm trying to implement responsive navigation without any frameworks. So far I got it to work, show the links and hide them when clicked and all that, but I noticed that it does not just toggle when the actual button is clicked, but the whole area of the navbar.

I am not sure if I've messed up something in the JS or the HTML. Still at the beginning of learning things, don't judge me :D

Demo: https://sweetdandelions.github.io/Liberto-photography/

HTML:

```
  <nav>
        <div class="burger">
            <i class="fas fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links tabs">
            <li id="tab-1" class="tab-item selected">Portraits</li>
            <li id="tab-2" class="tab-item ">Weddings</li>
            <li id="tab-3" class="tab-item ">Animals</li>
            <li id="tab-4" class="tab-item ">Landscape</li>
            <li id="tab-5" class="tab-item ">Blog</li>
            <li id="tab-6" class="tab-item ">About</li>
            <li id="tab-7" class="tab-item ">Price List</li>
            <li id="tab-8" class="tab-item ">Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS (inside a media query, .burger is display: none outside it)

```
    .burger {
            display: block;
        }

        .nav-links {
            display: none;
        }

        .nav-links li {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 20px;
            display: none;
        }

        .active {
            display: block;
        }
```

JS:

```
    // Mobile menu nav
    const nav = () => {
        // Get the menu button
        const menu = document.querySelector('.burger');

        // Get the nav ul content
        const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');

        // Get all the links from the ul
        const links = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

        // Get button to be changed on click - Ignore this for now
        const icon = document.querySelector('.fa-bars');

        // When menu button clicked
        menu.addEventListener('click', () => {

            // Display the content in the nav ul
            nav.classList.toggle('active');

            console.log(nav);

            // Show links
            links.forEach((link) => {
                link.style.display = 'block';
            });

        });

        console.log(menu);

        // After link is clicked, close menu
        tabItems.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', () => {
            nav.classList.remove('active');
        }));
    }

    // Call function
    nav();
```

Comment: Please provide a working snippet or fiddle with minimal code for reproducing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `menu.addEventListener('click' ...` to `icon.addEventListener('click' ...`.

You're telling js to listen clicks event on the `menu` element, i.e. your `<div class="burger">`, instead of `<i class="fas fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>`.

Comment: Damn, that was easy. I guess sometimes all we need is another pair of eyes. Thanks a lot! Plus, I can just change the selector for the menu to be .burger i, that works too.

Comment: No problem, I too should use the [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) technique more regularly when I stumble across unsolvable problem :)